# Is there a way to know whether a user/role is allowed to access kubernetes objects using only AWS API/SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

I want to check whether a user/role ARN is added in a cluster `aws-auth` configmap. Few ways to do that is either by using `eksctl` and `kubectl` cli commands and checking. I want to do it programatically using [Kubernetes nodejs API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-eks/index.html) .

I also figured that AWS console make a request to skylens endpoint (see image). But this endpoint is not listed in the nodejs API.

[image]